# Proving $‖\exp(Ax)-e^{-\eta x}\sum_{n=0}^l\frac{(\eta x)^n}{n!}P^n‖<\epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

I'm having trouble knowing where to start with this assignment.

Let $A = \{a_{ij}\}_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$ be a matrix, and let $\eta = max_i(-a_{ii})>0$.

With $P=I+\frac{1}{\eta}A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Let $‖\cdot‖$ be the matrix norm induced by the maximum norm for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that

$$‖\exp(Ax)-e^{-\eta x}\sum_{n=0}^l\frac{(\eta x)^n}{n!}P^n‖<\epsilon$$

if

$$\sum_{n=0}^l\frac{(\eta x)^n}{n!}e^{-\eta x}>1-\epsilon$$

I've shown that

$$\exp(Ax)=-e^{-\eta x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\eta x)^n}{n!}P^n$$

Comment: What is $ P $?  And please proofread your sentence defining $ \| \cdot \| $, it doesn't make sense because it is not a matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry! It's fixed now.

Comment: There are multiple ways in which a norm for $ \mathbb{R}^n $ can "induce" a norm for $ \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}{\mathbb{R}} $.  It's much easier to simply say "Let $ \| \cdot \| $ be the maximum norm $ \| A \| := \mathrm{max}{\{a_{ij}\}} $."  Since you're dealing with a very precise estimate here, the precise definition of the norm is important.  I'm not even sure if this is the one you meant.

Comment: The text above is taken directly from my assignment, but I assume that it is $‖‖_{\infty} = max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$